# Using Salesforce as IDP for community plus users on an external company site?

Tags: community, apexrest, authentication, embedded-services, identity-provider

I got tasked with these requirements I am kind of lost on. Was wondering if anyone here has had a similar ask or can provide suggestions for how to go about this?

We have an external company website that wants to use our Salesforce community implementation as the IDP for their website. Users will be able to register from the external site and on the Salesforce side we will introduce them as users in our existing community implementation. The external site will allow login with these user credentials to get user information and some sort of Salesforce session token. This token will be used to authenticate and callout to various Apex REST services we will create so the external site can interact with our database. There is also a need in some areas of the external site to be able to link and bridge directly into a community portal session in Salesforce.

What I have so far isn't much. It seems like embedded login can be used to authenticate into Salesforce and a hybrid web app. We can add the community user's profile to this connected app to allow them to authenticate into Salesforce. We then use this token to access our REST endpoints. I'm hoping we can then use this token again in some way with frontdoor.jsp to link into our Salesforce portal automatically logged in.

Does anyone know how I could go about this? Am I even close?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a "Connected App" in Salesforce which will allow you to grant an OAuth "Access Token" to your external website. This token can be used to access Salesforce data on behalf of your users from the external website.

When users need to login, they will do so from the Salesforce community, and will be redirected to the external site via OAuth "flow".

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5

You can either use a "User Agent" or "Web Server" flow depending on whether you need access from the external app's backend.

Something to note is you will have to provision community users in Salesforce. One way is for the external site to do this via API.